# grouping common results in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a products table, with the fields product, category and cost, of type varchar, varchar and decimal.

I then have a sales table, with the fields client, productname, quantity, cost, and saledate, of type varchar, varchar, int, decimal and date.

I want to show all of the products sold for a month, say the current month.

However, I don´t want to show every sale individually. I want to automatically add all of one product together and show it as one row.

In the sales table, the cost for each sales record is already multiplied by the quantity.

So for example, to if 5 beers were purchased, it would returned as one row showing name as beers, quanity as 5, and cost as however much.

I need something like say:

```
Select product, cost from sales, WHERE sales.product=products.name 
AND category='food' AND WHERE month(date_field) = month(getdate())
```

This should show all the sales for a certain category of product for the current month, but is there an easy way to "group" products together?

I would have to take into account the quantity field in the sales table, because one sale is not necessarily only one product

A hopefully clearer example, one sale record maybe for 2 beers for one client with a cost of 10, and another sales record may be to a different client with a quantity of 3 and cost of 15. I want just one record that would say for beer, 5 were sold and the total cost is 25.

I have no idea where to go from as far as I have gotten...

Comment: The problem may run deeper than the query to select product sales. It may be that your table structure could be improved. Please can you edit your question, and add the output from `CREATE TABLE`, for each of your tables. You mention a `purchases` table, but that doesn't appear in your query - how does that relate to the other two tables?

Comment: I described the table structure at the start of my question though? I have removed the purchases table from my question, as it is not relevant. - I´m just trying to prevent the question from being needlessly long.

Comment: From your table descriptions and example query, it looks as though you have related the tables via the VARCHAR `product` column. If you change the name of a `product` in the `products` table, the relationship will break unless you then update the `product_name` in the `sales` table. You *might* have actually joined the tables using a primary key instead, but this is not clear from your question. My point was that with a little more information, you would help respondents to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like

```
Select product, cost from sales,products WHERE sales.product=products.name 
AND category='food' AND month(date_field) = month(getdate())
```

To get a listing of the items linked as you suggest according to the category in the products tables.

To get the summary by category you need something like:

```
Select category,SUM(Sales.Quantity),SUM(Sales.cost) from 
sales,products WHERE sales.product=products.name 
AND category='food' AND month(date_field) = month(getdate()) group by category
```

This will work but there is a lot to criticise in your database structure, specifically to link products by name as you do is not very reliable.

Comment: Hi Elemental, even trying the solution above, I can´t get it to work. I mainly get the error that the field cost is ambiguous, and that FUNCTION mytable.getdate does not exist. I fixed the ambiguity, I think, but could not get past the function error.

Comment: Indeed - however there ARE relevant mysql functions that serve the you needs in the position of month and getdate in your example. I suggest you consult the docs of scalar functions regarding dates.

Comment: I have had getdate working before, it just seems to be in the query you posted. I also can´t get past the ambiguity error, should I use sales.cost from sales AND products.cost from products instead of just cost from sales, products ?

Comment: Have changed the solution slightly to remove your ambiguity and include the cost as you have defined it in your edited question

Answer (score 0):

This question looks awfully familiar...

The answer is a SQL GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT product, SUM(quantity) FROM sales s, products p WHERE product=p.name AND category='food' AND month(date_field)=month(getdate()) GROUP BY product
```

The SUM(quantity) above will tally up all the units sold of a particular product in the given month.

Comment: I don´t think I have asked a similar question before, my other question was to do with date ranges?

Comment: in your solution, the cost is not returned at all? Is it possible to return the cost based on the quantity?

Comment: Just noting that I just came off a question from you about the step before this.  No harm intended.

Comment: Yes, you can return the cost using the below SUM(quantity*cost)

Comment: No harm taken, just worried I was maybe doing something wrong. I updated my question in case you didn´t see, but the cost in sales is already multipled by the quantity, so I don´t want to multiply it again...I gave an example which hopefully makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) and [COUNT](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT productname, cost, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM sales LEFT JOIN products ON sales.product = products.productname 
WHERE category='food' AND month(date_field) = month(getdate())
GROUP BY productname
```